# InputAutoReplacement inside an Inline Cell

Tags: replacement, input

I use InputAutoReplacements to speed up my textual writing.  Consider the code below.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 InputAutoReplacements -> {".xbar" -> 
    FormBox[OverscriptBox["x", "_"], TraditionalForm]}]
```

While inside a text cell, the code above results in an x with a bar over it whenever I type ".xbar" and then space bar.  This works great however, if I am in an inline cell within a text cell, it doesn't seem to work.

The problem has something to do with the period, ".".  If I change the code above by replacing ".xbar" with "sxbar", (switching out the "." with an "s") everything works fine in both a text cell and the inline cell.

However, I prefer my InputAutoReplacements start with a period "." because all periods in my documents are followed by a space or an integer.  Doing it this way make my shortcuts more unique and hence cuts down on unintentional mistakes, as those who work with InputAutoReplacements are appreciative of.

What's the issue with using a period, ".", in an inline cell?  And how I can fix it?  I tried changing the DefaultNewInlineCellStyle in the Options Inspector to "Text" but still doesn't work.

Ideas?

Edit:  FYI...

Below is the cell data after I type ".xbar" and then spacebar in a text cell

```
Cell[TextData[{
 Cell[BoxData[
  FormBox[
   OverscriptBox["x", "_"], TraditionalForm]]],
 " "
}], "Text"]
```

Below is the cell data after I type ".xbar" and then spacebar in an inline cell inside a text cell.

```
Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  RowBox[{".", "xbar "}], TraditionalForm]],
 FormatType->"TraditionalForm"]], "Text"]
```

Comment: What are the boxes like? I'm guessing the inline cell is using some format that doesn't quite work with the replacements.

Comment: Inline cells work perfect with replacements.  Notice “sxbar” works perfect and I’ve been using them for a while.  The issue is using the period “.” as part of the call for the replacement.  Yes it seems there is something different about the format.  That’s what I’m asking about.  Is there a way to make the format the same?

Comment: I just checked and the inline cell uses a box format. That's your issue. You'll have to change the `DefaultNewInlineCellStyle` or `DefaultInlineFormatType`. Try setting `DefaultInlineFormatType->DefaultTextInlineFormatType` or something.

Comment: I see! I'll check it out and get back!  TY!  I updated the question with your request for cell data.

Comment: Hmmm... didn't work.  To me that seems like that should have done it.

Comment: It seems both of those still use a box form for the inline cell. Short of creating an inline cell and removing the `BoxData` yourself there's not much else I can see here, though I'll keep looking. On the other hand most symbol-like forms won't be parsed into a new box so those can be used as easy replacements. Problem is most of those require an input alias, so why not just add to `InputAliases` at that point...

Comment: See also this from the docs: "In textual input, automatic replacements can be performed on strings of alphanumeric characters delimited by spaces or other punctuation characters." So that's something you'll have to contend with. But this is your problem: "In expression input, automatic replacements can be performed only on strings of characters that correspond to complete input tokens. " `BoxData` implies "expression input"

Comment: Can I chat with you for a min?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65099/discussion-between-b3m2a1-and-michael-mccain).

Comment: (see the chat) I wanted `ParentList`, not `InheritedList`